# Capture __LINE__ and __FILE__ without #define

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to determine a "modern" implementation for the following C-style code:

```
#define logError(...) log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Is is possible to capture this using variadic templates or something similar that does not rely on a `#define` ?

Desired use case:

```
logError( "Oh no! An error occurred!" );
```

Where `__FILE__`, and `__LINE__` are captured under the hood, but reflect the file name and line number of where `logError` was called from.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Macro exists for a reason and you are allow to use it if necessary.

Comment: You're sort of asking to create soft breakpoints with this sort of logging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the preprocessor is the only choice when you want to work with line numbers and filenames.

For the compiler it's not possible to use line numbers and filenames as arguments for function calls (or storing them in a variable).

In my company we had the exactly same issue with logging. We ended up with an external script scanning the source files and then building proper functions to call.

Answer (score 22):

Macros are indeed your only choice, at least until [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) makes it into the standard and fulfills your wish.

Comment: `std::source_location` is now supported in GCC apparently https://godbolt.org/z/EsEY8T