# Create constrexpr function with macro behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, constexpr

I have a macro function which works as you would expect:

```
#define PRECONDITION(testBool) ( !(testBool) ?              \
    ( fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Precondition '%s' failed.\n", \
              __FILE__, __LINE__, #testBool),               \
      exit(1) ) : void(sizeof(0)) )
```

This is great, since I can create nice assertions:

```
PRECONDITION(5 > 6); // prints "<file>:<line>: Precondition '5 > 6' failed."
```

While this works, I'm trying to learn a better and more modern way of doing this,
using `constexpr`, so I can have type safety, use `std::err <<`.
However, I have not been able to find a source stating how to do this / whether or not it
is actually possible, so I ask here. What I image is something along the lines of:

```
constexpr void PRECONDITION(bool testBool)
{
    if(testBool) { return; }
    std::cerr << __SOME_MAGIC__ << ":" << __SOME_MAGIC__ << ":"
        << "Precondition '" << __SOME_MAGIC__ << "' failed." << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: The constexpr is doable. You'll have to wait for [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) in c++20 to avoid the macro magic.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36851551/3233393

Comment: You can get the file & line information either with C++20 features or with some GCC extensions, but I don't think there's a way to get the argument as a string.

Comment: What "type safety" are you looking for? The code in the macro requires that `!(testBool)` be convertible to `bool`. If it's not, the code won't compile. And, of course, you can use `std::cerr` rather than `fprintf` inside that macro. Yes, people discourage use of macros, but neither of your stated goals requires such a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** Macro expansion is just a textual transform of the source code. Once transformed by macro definitions, source code is "given" to the compiler to compile it. So, macros are expanded before compiler has even started doing its job while `constexpr` functions are executed on compile time. Therefore, macros and `constexpr` expressions are 2 different things.

Comment: I guess that implies, also following comment by @cigien, that with C++20 we can have alternatives for `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, but perhaps never for `#testBool`. Still, thanks for clarifying!